# error in compilation with ld : __stack_chk_guard@@GLIBC_2.17

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, odroid

I am compiling some files on the odroidC2 board (armv8-64bit) running Ubuntu 16.04.1, and I got the following error:

```
odroid@odroid64:~/flext-master/tutorial/simple1$ g++ -fPIC -L/usr/lib -pthread -shared -Wl,-S -L/usr/local/src/pd/bin -L/usr/local/lib -o pd-linux/release-single/simple1.pd_linux   pd-linux/release-single/main.opp  -lflext-pd_s 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libflext-pd_s.a(libflext_pd_s_la-flxlet.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against external symbol `__stack_chk_guard@@GLIBC_2.17' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libflext-pd_s.a(libflext_pd_s_la-flxlet.o)(.text+0x344): unresolvable R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 relocation against symbol `__stack_chk_guard@@GLIBC_2.17'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see the -fPIC option is present. So I don't understand why the compiler suggest to "recompile with -fPIC". Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the `pd-linux/release-single/main.opp` (BTW, maybe .cpp?) that you're compiling with `-fPIC`, but in the `libflext-pd_s.a` archive that contains an object `libflext_pd_s_la-flxlet.o` which is not compiled with `-fPIC`, so you need to recompile flext library properly.